# Can not get parent div to span with child div 3 childs

Tags: css, html

The green box is supposed to be IN the blue box. But it is not. Can somebody tell me why and how to solve it?" http://jsfiddle.net/6MN8R

-------- original question -----------

The sides of this are not expanding to the .content child div... i've been through overflow and i am clearing the div at the end of the last child can anyone help me?

Main is the parent div and the child div spawns off of that one.

When I change the height in main it works fine but i need to work dynamically

```
#main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('../images/top.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#main .leftside {
    float: left;
    width: 47px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/left.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#main .rightside {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/right.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#main .content {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
    top: 36px;
    width: 92%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
 }
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id='main'>
    <div class='leftside'>
        <img src='images/tleft.jpg' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div class='rightside'>
        <img src='images/tright.jpg' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try creating a http://jsfiddle.net . I read this twice and what you are asking is unclear. `The sides of this are not expanding to the .content child div`. What is 'this'?

Comment: Yes sorry the .content div is the div that should be expanding the parent div main which would change the sizes of the .leftside and .rightside div's thus repeating the background-image on the y axis. If i set a static height to main than it works fine. But i don't want to set a static height to that i want it to expand with the .content div

Comment: Yeah... that's not helping. Try creating the problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Still the same thing happening in jsfiddle, i need the parent div #main to grow in height with the child div .content

Comment: When you create the jsfiddle their is a 'save' button in the menu bar. When you save the url will change to be unique. You can cut and paste this into SO so that others can see and update the code. When you  make updates you resave the fiddle and the url changes. It is a great tool for collaborating on code. If you post a fiddle URL I suspect you will have a solution within minutes.

Comment: Another tip - when creating fiddles you can use http://placehold.it/30x40 to substitute images in. The numbers represent x/y dimensions.

Comment: Here, I took the time to create your fiddle for you. It is so much easier to explain with a visual. "The green box is supposed to be IN the blue box. But it is not. Can somebody tell me why and how to solve it?" http://jsfiddle.net/6MN8R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `position: relative` on your content div. Just remove that. I made a couple other minor changes to your css and html - substituting in some images and making the content fit between the left and right divs, but I think that was your design intent anyways.

http://jsfiddle.net/6MN8R/1/

You may be asking yourself why this happens. You set position relative and the top to 36px. Forget about all the floats, the side divs, and all that other crap. When you set something to relative and reposition it with top, left, right, or bottom it can move OUT of its parent container. It still affects the parent container size, but not its location. The content div caused the parent container to grow, but the position top caused it to also move down and out of main div.

Comment: shouldn't the background-image span down the entire div than? It doesn't in this example

Comment: The background image specified in the CSS is an invalid URL. Try editing the fiddle with a valid image and I would expect it to repeat.